# Print the sum of the list using functions in Python

Tags: python, function

```
sum=0
def sum_list(list):
    for x in list:
        sum=sum+x
        return sum
list=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(sum_list)
```

The output of the code is :  `<function sum_list at 0x10d06a1e0>`

Why is it pointing to the memory address not the sum of the list?

Comment: Why not just use ```print(sum(list))``` to begin with?

Comment: `sum(list)` would work?

Comment: You need `sum_list(list)`. Also avoid using `list` as a variable name since it overwrites the build in list class.

Comment: ...and avoid using `sum` as a variable name, since it overwrites the built-in `sum` function, which happens to be a function which does what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also, your code return the sum after the first iteration.  The return statement should be outside of the for loop if you want to get an accurate sum.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the list array like this:-

```
def sum_list(lst):
  sum = 0
  for x in lst:
    sum=sum+x
  return sum

lst=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(sum_list(lst))
```

Comment: I know it's in the OP, but you shouldn't use `list` as a variable.  It overwrites the builtin.

Comment: As previous commenter said, avoid using protected keyword name "list".

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `sum()`. If you cannot and want to `sum` using a function, please change your variable names!

When you call the inbuilt function `sum` it returns

```
sum
<built-in function sum>

myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1155]
sum(myList)
#1165
```

Now if you do what you have done, and set `sum` to 0 it returns

```
sum
0
```

This renders you unable to use the function `sum`

```
sum = 0
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sum(mylist)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    sum(mylist)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: yes, I forgot that. My return statement was at the wrong place, thank you all for the feedback!!